# What is the returned value?

Tags: pass-by-reference

In a language that passes parameters by reference, given the following function:

```
int function g(x, y) {
  x = x + 1;
  y = y + 2;
  return x + y;
}
```

If `i = 3`, and `g(i,i)` is called, what is value returned? I thought it is `9`, is this correct?

Comment: This looks like homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: C doesn't have references, and although that typically means "via pointer", there's none in your question. Can you include an actual C function so we can answer your question? In any case, if `x` and `y` do somehow refer to the same variable, `x + y` will always be an even number, as it's equivalent to `2 * x`.

Comment: Removed C tag as C does not pass parameters by reference

Comment: You think it is 9. How did you arrive at that conclusion? Please show your working, with the value of i after each line of the function.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr: Why edit it to make it *even less* valid C? Let the OP fix his code.

Comment: @Matt: Hint - if x and y both refer to the same variable, you can just replace both x and y with z and see what the code does.

Comment: @GMan -- I didn't realize it was C code, I was just trying to make it readable and obvious that the function being referenced was the one defined above.

Answer (score 2):

If it's pass-by-reference (your original question was C but C doesn't have pass-by-reference and the question has changed since then anyway, so I'll answer generically), it's probably the case that `x` and `y` will simply modify the variables that are passed in for them. That's what a reference is, after all.

In this case, they're *both* a reference to the *same* variable `i`, so your sequence is likely to be:

```
i = i + 1;       // i becomes 4.
i = i + 2;       // i becomes 6.
return i + i;    // return i + i, or 12.
```

You can see this in operation with the following C (using pointers to emulate pass-by-reference):

```
pax$ cat qq.c
#include <stdio.h>

int g(int *x, int *y) {
    *x = *x + 1;
    *y = *y + 2;
    return *x + *y;
}

int main (void) {
    int i = 3;
    int rv = g (&i, &i);
    printf ("Returned: %d\n", rv);
    return 0;
}

pax$ gcc -o qq qq.c ; ./qq
Returned: 12
```

---

Your result of 9 seems to be assuming that the references are distinct from one another, such as in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int g(int *x, int *y) {
    *x = *x + 1;
    *y = *y + 2;
    return *x + *y;
}

int main (void) {
    int i1 = 3, i2 = 3;
    int rv = g (&i1, &i2);
    printf ("Returned: %d\n", rv);
    return 0;
}
```

(this *does* output 9) but that's not usually the case with reference types.